# Specify git user OUTside requirements.txt

Tags: git, pip

I have a successful `requirements.txt` that looks something like

```
-e .
-e git+https://OTHER_USER@github.com/ORGANIZATION/PACKAGE.git#egg=PACKAGE
package-two==3.0.4
    ...
```

How can I specify OTHER_USER *outside* of the `requirements.txt`?

Specification of OTHER_USER is necessary, as consumers of `requirements.txt` must authenticate to receive PACKAGE.  Some of them have accounts that differ from their host logins, though.

Why not keep the `OTHER_USER@github.com` syntax?  At that point, different users have different `requirements.txt`-s, and maintenance becomes far more complicated.

I like to think there's a way to communicate to `pip` or git (if not both) that I am OTHER_USER rather than `$USER`.

Assume the client is Unix-like:  Linux, MacOS, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git can [substitute one URL with the other on the fly](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-urlltbasegtinsteadOf). So put `https://github.com/ORGANIZATION/PACKAGE.git` into `requirements.txt` and ask everyone to configure git:

```
git config --global url."https://USER@github.com/ORGANIZATION/PACKAGE.git".insteadOf https://github.com/ORGANIZATION/PACKAGE.git
```

Comment: Perfect.    I am having enough trouble with mini-Markdown that I'll truncate my response:  this is just the help I sought, and I thank you for it.